# Module Not Found error : No module named 'statsmodels'

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter-notebook

I am using python 3.6 (checked using `python -v`) and am trying to "import statsmodels.api as sm" in my jupyter notebook. However, it shows module not found error even after I have installed `statsmodels` from my command line.

When I run: `pip install statsmodels` or `pip3 install statsmodels` 
It says

```
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\17372\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from patsy>=0.4.0->statsmodels) (1.12.0)
```

Somebody suggested installing `scipy` before `statsmodels`, I've done that too.

The kernel in my jupyter notebook says "Python 3"

Comment: What are the results of `where python` and `where pip`?